# Error creating bean with name 'jwtDecoderByJwkKeySetUri' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am having this error while trying to run the ResourceServer, it complains about the: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/xxxnapp/protocol/openid-connect/certs as it has no protocol

> Error creating bean with name 'jwtDecoderByJwkKeySetUri' defined in
> class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/servlet/OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration$JwtDecoderConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder]:
> Factory method 'jwtDecoderByJwkKeySetUri' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JWK Set URL
> "=
> http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/xxxnapp/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
> : no protocol: =
> http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/xxxnapp/protocol/openid-connect/certs

any idea how I over come this error.

Comment: It looks as though you have an extra '=' at the start of your URL. Can you add your application.properties file to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an additional "=" before the url in the proprieties file which is causing the error. by modifying it I have my program running.